# Stuck at removing/adding multiple taxes from a value?

Tags: c#, finance

I have to remove/add multiple taxes or adjustments from a value to get back to the original value that it was applied to.  I will define what an adjustment can be:

An adjustment can be a percentage that is either compounded or non-compounded.  It can also be a flat dollar amount.  It can also be added or removed to the initial value.  I just have to write the part that reverses the taxes from the post-tax value.  I wrote something up I could use to generate test data and I wrote something else that would reverse those adjustments from the post-tax value generated by the test data.  I think I am overengineering for applying the adjustments and unapplying them.  The adjustments are applied order, so a list containing (+7% non-compounded, +3% compounded, + 5% non-compounded) would have the 7 applied first, then the 3 and then the 5 and in this case, I believe to remove it I have to go backwards, meaning remove the 5, then the 3 and then the 7.  Here is my program to apply the adjustments to an initial value (it should bring back 115.21, but in this case it is bringing back 115.0)

```
void Main()
{
Adjustment a1 = new Adjustment {Amount = 7.0M, IsCompounded = false, Add = true, Percent = true};
Adjustment a2 = new Adjustment {Amount = 3.0M, IsCompounded = true, Add = true, Percent = true};
Adjustment a3 = new Adjustment {Amount = 5.0M, IsCompounded = false,  Add = true ,Percent = true};



List<Adjustment> adjustments = new List<Adjustment>();
adjustments.Add(a1);
adjustments.Add(a2);
adjustments.Add(a3);


decimal total = 100m;

decimal adjustedTotal = total;

decimal nonCompoundValues = 0.0m;
string prevTypeCalc = "";
decimal compoundValues = 1.0m;
decimal percents = 1.0m;

int i = 0;

foreach(Adjustment a in adjustments)
{
    if(a.Percent)
    {
        if(a.IsCompounded)
        {
            if(a.Add)
            {
                compoundValues *= a.CompoundedValue;
            }
            else
            {
                compoundValues /= a.CompoundedValue;
            }

            prevTypeCalc = "Compound";
        }
        else if(!a.IsCompounded)
        {
            if(a.Add)
            {
                nonCompoundValues += a.AmountFraction;
            }
            else
            {
                nonCompoundValues -= a.AmountFraction;
            }

            prevTypeCalc = "Non-Compound";
        }
    }
    else
    {

        if(prevTypeCalc == "Non-Compound" || prevTypeCalc == "Compound")
        {
            if(nonCompoundValues <= 0)
                adjustedTotal *= compoundValues - Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
            else
                adjustedTotal *= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);

            compoundValues = 1.0m;
            nonCompoundValues = 0.0m;   
        }

        if(a.Add)
        {   
            adjustedTotal += a.Amount;
        }
        else
        {
            adjustedTotal -= a.Amount;
        }

        prevTypeCalc = "Flat";

    }
}

if(prevTypeCalc == "Non-Compound" || prevTypeCalc == "Compound")
{

    if(nonCompoundValues <= 0)
        adjustedTotal *= compoundValues - Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
    else
        adjustedTotal *= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
}

Console.WriteLine(adjustedTotal);

}


public class Adjustment
{
public bool Percent {get;set;}
public decimal Amount {get;set;}
public bool IsCompounded {get;set;}
public bool Add{get;set;}
public decimal AmountFraction
{
get {
    return Amount/100.0M;
}
}
public decimal CompoundedValue
{
    get{
        return 1 + AmountFraction;
    }
}
}
```

Here is the algorithm for unapplying the adjustments from teh previous algorithm.  Notice, I have reversed the order in when I add them to the list, so when I take 115.21, I get back to 100:

```
 void Main()
 {
Adjustment a1 = new Adjustment {Amount = 7.0M, IsCompounded = false, Add = false, Percent = true};
Adjustment a2 = new Adjustment {Amount = 3.0M, IsCompounded = true, Add =false, Percent = true};
Adjustment a3 = new Adjustment {Amount = 5.0M, IsCompounded = false, Add = false, Percent = true};


List<Adjustment> adjustments = new List<Adjustment>();

adjustments.Add(a3);
adjustments.Add(a2);
adjustments.Add(a1);

decimal total = 115.21m;
int i = 0;
decimal adjustedTotal = total;

decimal nonCompoundValues = 0.0m;
string prevTypeCalc = "";
decimal compoundValues = 1.0m;
bool nonCompoundFirst = true;
bool first = true;
foreach(Adjustment a in adjustments)
{
    if(a.Percent)
    {
        if(a.IsCompounded)
        {
            if(a.Add)
            {
                compoundValues *= a.CompoundedValue;
            }
            else
            {
                if(prevTypeCalc == "")
                compoundValues = a.CompoundedValue;
                else
                compoundValues /= a.CompoundedValue;
            }

            prevTypeCalc = "Compound";
        }
        else if(!a.IsCompounded)
        {
            if(a.Add)
            {
                nonCompoundValues += a.AmountFraction;
            }
            else
            {
                nonCompoundValues -= a.AmountFraction;
            }


            prevTypeCalc = "Non-Compound";

        }
    }
    else
    {

    if(prevTypeCalc == "Non-Compound" || prevTypeCalc == "Compound")
    {
        if(nonCompoundValues <= 0 && compoundValues != 1) //Non-Compound
            adjustedTotal *= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
        else if(nonCompoundValues <= 0 && compoundValues == 1) //Compound
            adjustedTotal /= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
        else
            adjustedTotal /= compoundValues - Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues); //Compound + Non-Compound

        compoundValues = 1.0m;
        nonCompoundValues = 0.0m;   
    }

    if(a.Add)
        adjustedTotal += a.Amount;
    else
        adjustedTotal -= a.Amount;

        prevTypeCalc = "Flat";
    }
}

if(prevTypeCalc == "Non-Compound" || prevTypeCalc == "Compound")
{
    if(nonCompoundValues <= 0 && compoundValues != 1) 
        adjustedTotal /= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
    else if(nonCompoundValues <= 0 && compoundValues == 1) //Non-compound
        adjustedTotal /= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
    else
        adjustedTotal /= compoundValues - Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues); 


}

Console.WriteLine(adjustedTotal);

}


public class Adjustment
{
public bool Percent {get;set;}
public decimal Amount {get;set;}
public bool IsCompounded {get;set;}
public bool Add{get;set;}
public decimal AmountFraction
{
get {
    return Amount/100.0M;
}
}
public decimal CompoundedValue
{
    get{
        return 1 + AmountFraction;
    }
}
}
```

The main problem I have is that I can get it to work if all the adjustment are compound or if they are all non-compound or if they are all flat, but it gets crazy when I start mixing compound and non-compound percentages with the fact that I can add or remove them as well, for example (+5% non-compound, -2$, -3% compound, +4% non-compound)

Non-Compounded Tax is removed or added based up the initial amount, so if your initial amount is 100 and you have a non-compounding taxes of +3% and -4%, you first add 3% of 100 to get 103 and then you subtract 4% of 100 from 103 to get 99.

If 4% was compounded, you would take the 4% off the 103, not the 100, so it would be:

103 / 1.04 = 99.03846.....

Scenarios based upon Lasse's answer:

Adding all non-compound percentages passes.
Subtracting all non-compound percentages passes.
Adding all compound percentages passes.
Adding all flat amounts passes. 
Subtracting all flat amounts passes.
Adding non-compound/compound percentages passes.

Subtracting all compound percentages fails:

Using -7%, -3%, -5%.  with a calculator:

100/ 1.07 / 1.03 / 1.05 = 86.41511227483462, but I get 85.6995000

Subtracting Non-Compound/Compound fails:

Using -7% compound, -3% non-compound, -5% compound, with a calculator:

((100 / 1.07) - 3) / 1.05 = 86.1504..., but I get 85.50000.

Basically, it starts not producing the correct results when I mix compounding/non-compounding with adding and subtracting the amounts.

Adjustments that don't pass:

```
var adjustments = new Adjustment[]
{
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(-7M),
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(-3M),
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(-5M)
};

var adjustments = new Adjustment[]
{
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(+7M),
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(-3M),
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(-5M)
};

var adjustments = new Adjustment[]
{
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(+7M),
    new NonCompoundTaxAdjustment(-3M),
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(5M)
};

var adjustments = new Adjustment[]
{
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(+7M),
    new FlatValueAdjustment(-3M),
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(5M)
};
```

Lasse, I wen through the scenarios again and I made a comment about this already, but I believe I am doing my calculation wrong with the calculator.  After doing the calculation a different way, my numbers matched up with yours and all scenarios passed.  For example, given:

```
var adjustments = new Adjustment[]
{
    new NonCompoundTaxAdjustment(7M),
    new NonCompoundTaxAdjustment(3M),
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(-5M)
};
```

I was doing this with the calculator (100 * 1.1) / 1.05 = 104.761904, but then I tried

100 * 1.1 = 110
110 * 0.05 = 5.5
110 - 5.5 = 104.5 which is what matches up with your calculations, so I guess you handle it this way.

A thought:

If you subtract 7% from 100 and do it this way:

100 - (100 * 0.07) = 93. it seems like it is incorrect now because to add 7% back, which is 93 * 1.07, you don't get 100, you get 99.51.  Subtracting 7% from 100 should actually be 100/1.07 = 93.45 and when you take 93.45 * 1.07, you get back to 100

I am stuck at something here.

The current code only appears to handle adding percentages correctly.  For example, if i add a +7% to 200, I get 214 which is correct and to get back to 200, the code does 214/1.07 which is also correct.  The problem is that if I want to remove 7% from 214, the code is doing .93 * 200 = 186, which is incorrect.  7% removed from 200 is actually 200/1.07 = 186.9158878504673.  Taking this value and multiplying it by 7% or 186.9158878504673 * 1.07 = 200, but if I take 186 * 1.07, I get 199.02 which is not 200.

Comment: Could you give a textual description of what a compounded and non-compounded tax is, for all of us that aren't English? Then you would have a larger audience that might be able to help with your question.

Comment: I updated the post about compound and non-compound. Let me know if it is clear.

Comment: Would that mean that your example of 7% non-compounded, 3% compounded, and 5% compounded is equivalent to the formula, where X is the start value: `total = x * 1.07 * 1.03 + x * 0.05` ?

Comment: In this example, yes, that would be correct:  (100 * 1.07) * 1.03 + (100 * 0.05)

Comment: If that is the case, then I'm afraid you have a problem, you won't be able to just "remove" the values, since the amount to remove in the case of non-compounded tax depends on the final result. In other words, the result to remove is a function of what you have left, after having removed it. If you start combining the 3 types of adjustments (compounded, non-compounded, and a flat tax), you need to generate an equation for what the result is, compared to the original value, then you need to solve that equation.

Comment: Example: 1% compounded, 1% non-compounded, flat value of 1, 1% compounded, 1% non-compounded, 1% compounded. Formula then becomes: `((X * 1.01 + X * 0.01 + 1) * 1.01 + X * 0.01) * 1.01`. This can be simplified to: `X * 1.050602 + 1.0201`. From that you can calculate backwards.

Comment: Yes, this is what I am stuck at.

Comment: @Lasse, one of the issues I have is that my math is not very strong, so when I am looping through, I don't know which taxes I can combine and I am not sure when I can adjust the total as opposed to simplifying the problem?

Comment: If you hang on, I'll post some code (I hope.)

Comment: Ok, thanks so far...  How far are you from Bergen?  That is where my Grandmother lives?

Comment: I guessed that, I never heard of it.

Comment: Porsgrunn: http://maps.google.no/maps?f=q&source=s_q&hl=no&geocode=&q=porsgrunn&aq=&sll=60.137698,-1.273984&sspn=0.016582,0.038581&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Porsgrunn,+Telemark&z=12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the way I did it.  It works for most situations, especially if you put the non-compounding percentages first.  If anyone has any improvements or notices any bugs, please let me know:

```
void Main()
{
Adjustment a1 = new Adjustment {Amount = 12.0M, IsCompounded = false, Add = false, Percent = false};
Adjustment a2 = new Adjustment {Amount = 3.0M, IsCompounded = true, Add = true, Percent = true};
Adjustment a3 = new Adjustment {Amount = 5.0M, IsCompounded = true,  Add = true ,Percent = true};


List<Adjustment> adjustments = new List<Adjustment>();
adjustments.Add(a3);
adjustments.Add(a2);
adjustments.Add(a1);

decimal total = 103.55987055016181229773462783m;
decimal adjustedTotal = total;
decimal nonCompoundValues = 0.0m;
decimal compoundValues = 1.0m;
string prevType = "";

for(int i = 0; i <= adjustments.Count - 1; i++)
{

    if(adjustments[i].Percent)
    {
        if(adjustments[i].IsCompounded)
        {

            if(i == adjustments.Count - 1  && adjustments[i].IsCompounded)
            {
                if(adjustments[i].Add)
                {
                    nonCompoundValues += adjustments[i].Amount/100.0m;

                }
                else
                {
                    nonCompoundValues -= adjustments[i].Amount/100.0m;

                }
                break;
            }

            if(nonCompoundValues < 0  & prevType != "Compound") //Remove tax
            {

                adjustedTotal /= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
                nonCompoundValues = 0.0m;
                compoundValues = 1.0m;

            }
            else if(nonCompoundValues > 0 & prevType != "Compound") //Add tax
            {

                adjustedTotal *= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
                nonCompoundValues = 0.0m;
                compoundValues = 1.0m;
            }


            if(adjustments[i].Add)
            {

                if(prevType == "" || prevType == "Compound")
                {
                    adjustedTotal *= 1 + adjustments[i].Amount/100.0m; //add compound first
                    compoundValues = 1.0m;
                }
                else
                {
                    compoundValues *= 1 + adjustments[i].Amount/100.0m;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                if(prevType == "" || prevType == "Compound")
                {
                adjustedTotal /= 1 + adjustments[i].Amount/100.0m;

                compoundValues = 1.0m;
                }
                else
                {
                    compoundValues /= 1 + adjustments[i].Amount/100.0m;
                }
            }

            prevType = "Compound";

        }
        else // Non-Compound
        {

            if(adjustments[i].Add)
            {
                nonCompoundValues += adjustments[i].Amount/100.0m;

            }
            else
            {
                nonCompoundValues -= adjustments[i].Amount/100.0m;
            }

            prevType = "Non-compound";

        }

    }
    else //flat
    {
        if(nonCompoundValues < 0) //Remove tax
            {

                adjustedTotal /= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
                nonCompoundValues = 0.0m;
                compoundValues = 1.0m;

            }
            else if(nonCompoundValues > 0) //Add tax
            {

                adjustedTotal *= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
                nonCompoundValues = 0.0m;
                compoundValues = 1.0m;
            }

        if(adjustments[i].Add)
        {
            adjustedTotal += adjustments[i].Amount;
        }
        else
        {
            adjustedTotal -= adjustments[i].Amount;
        }

    }
}


if(nonCompoundValues < 0)
{

    adjustedTotal /= compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
}
else
{
    adjustedTotal *=compoundValues + Math.Abs(nonCompoundValues);
}
Console.WriteLine(adjustedTotal);

}


public class Adjustment
{
public bool Percent {get;set;}
public decimal Amount {get;set;}
public bool IsCompounded {get;set;}
public bool Add{get;set;}
public decimal AmountFraction
{
get {
    return Amount/100.0M;
}
}
public decimal CompoundedValue
{
    get{
        return 1 + AmountFraction;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's what I did.

I started with a formula consisting of two numbers, a factor and an offset.

The formula looks like this:

```
result = input * factor + offset
```

The formula starts out with a factor of 1, and an offset of 0, so basically the unadjusted formula looks like this:

```
result = input * 1 + 0
result = input * 1
result = input           <-- as expected
```

Then, for each adjustment, I adjust the formula as follows:

- Flat value: Add the flat value to the offset
- Compounded tax: multiply both the factor and the offset by `1 + PERCENTAGE/100`
- Noncompounded tax: add to the factor the value of `PERCENTAGE/100`. (**edit**: was 1+, that was incorrect)

This means that your example of:

- 7% Non-compounded tax
- 3% Compounded tax
- 5% Non-compounded tax

results in this:

```
result = input * factor + offset
result = input * 1      + 0
result = input * 1.07   + 0      <-- add 0.07 to factor
result = input * 1.1021 + 0      <-- multiply both factor and offset by 1.03
result = input * 1.1521 + 0      <-- add 0.05 to factor
```

To calculate how 100 would be, after adding the taxes, you feed it through the formula and get:

```
result = 100 * 1.1521 + 0
result = 115.21
```

To calculate how 115.21 was, before adding the taxes, you reverse the formula by solving it for input:

```
 result                    = input * factor + offset
 result - offset           = input * factor
(result - offset) / factor = input
                     input = (result - offset) / factor
```

So:

```
input = (result - 0) / 1.1521
input = result / 1.1521
```

and you get back your 100.

The code, which you can test in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) is as follows:

```
void Main()
{
    var adjustments = new Adjustment[]
    {
        new CompoundTaxAdjustment(7M),
        new NonCompoundTaxAdjustment(3M),
        new CompoundTaxAdjustment(5M)
    };

    var original = 100M;

    var formula = Adjustment.GenerateFormula(adjustments);

    var result = formula.Forward(original).Dump(); // prints 115,5
    var newOriginal = formula.Backward(result).Dump(); // prints 100
}

public abstract class Adjustment
{
    public class Formula
    {
        public decimal Factor = 1.0M;
        public decimal Offset;

        public decimal Forward(decimal input)
        {
            return input * Factor + Offset;
        }

        public decimal Backward(decimal input)
        {
            return (input - Offset) / Factor;
        }
    }

    public static Formula GenerateFormula(IEnumerable<Adjustment> adjustments)
    {
        Formula formula = new Formula();
        foreach (var adjustment in adjustments)
            adjustment.Adjust(formula);
        return formula;
    }

    protected abstract void Adjust(Formula formula);
}

public class FlatValueAdjustment : Adjustment
{
    private decimal _Value;

    public FlatValueAdjustment(decimal value)
    {
        _Value = value;
    }

    protected override void Adjust(Formula formula)
    {
        formula.Offset += _Value;
    }
}

public abstract class TaxAdjustment : Adjustment
{
    protected TaxAdjustment(decimal percentage)
    {
        Percentage = percentage;
    }

    protected decimal Percentage
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}

public class CompoundTaxAdjustment : TaxAdjustment
{
    public CompoundTaxAdjustment(decimal percentage)
        : base(percentage)
    {
    }

    protected override void Adjust(Formula formula)
    {
        var myFactor = 1M + Percentage / 100M;
        formula.Offset *= myFactor;
        formula.Factor *= myFactor;
    }
}

public class NonCompoundTaxAdjustment : TaxAdjustment
{
    public NonCompoundTaxAdjustment(decimal percentage)
        : base(percentage)
    {
    }

    protected override void Adjust(Formula formula)
    {
        formula.Factor += (Percentage / 100M);
    }
}
```

---

The example I gave, would look like this, let's do it manually first.

- 1% compounded, 1% non-compounded, flat value of 1, 1% compounded, 1% non-compounded, 1% compounded
- Start at 100, add 1% compounded tax, getting 101
- Add 1% non-compounded tax, 1% of 100, getting 102
- Add a flat value of 1, getting 103
- Add a 1% compoundex tax, getting 104,03
- Add a 1% non-compounded tax, 1% of 100, getting 105,03
- Add a 1% compounded tax, getting 106,0803

The input to the code:

```
var adjustments = new Adjustment[]
{
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(1M),
    new NonCompoundTaxAdjustment(1M),
    new FlatValueAdjustment(1M),
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(1M),
    new NonCompoundTaxAdjustment(1M),
    new CompoundTaxAdjustment(1M)
};
```

Output:

```
106,0803000
100
```

Comment: I am testing, while I test, you made the comment in your post "edit: was 1+, that was incorrect"  What did you mean by that? Was I doing something wrong and how close was my original code?

Comment: No, if you check the edits, the description of the adjustment said "Add `1 + PERCENTAGE/100`", that was incorrect (by me.) The code, however, was right, I just described it wrong.

Comment: Ok, I have tested some scenarios and most of it passed, I will update my post based on what passed and didn't

Comment: Yep, give me a concrete example of a failed scenario and I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Lasse, I think I spoke to soon, I checked the scenarios again and they passed.  I guess if I have a +7 non-compound, -3% compound, -5% compound, it is wrong to do (100 + 7) / 1.03 / 1.05.  Instead of dividing with the calculator, I am taking 3% of 107 and then subtracting and then taking 5% of that value and subtracting.  By doing it that way, your values match up. I always thought I could just divide, guess I was wrong in that part.

Comment: Lasse, so far it looks like everything has passed, I have tried many scenarios, sorry for my incorrect calculations, my math stinks :).  I do have some simple questions regarding your approach to this.  Maybe my code actually worked, but I was thinking it was not because I was incorrectly doing the calculations, but your code is cleaner.  I just have to convert it to VB.NET which I am not too knowledgeable of.  I post some simple questions about the program in the next comment.

Comment: How did you know the solution so quickly?  I have been struggling with this for a while?  Did I over-think it?  Why did you use abstract classes, could you have used interfaces as well?

Comment: I just thought of an important question.  If I want to subtract 7% from 100, isn't the formula actually 100/1.07 = 93.45.... because if you take 93.45 * 1.07, you get back to 100, but if you take 93 as you are doing and multiply that my 1.07, you don't get back to 100, you get 99.51

Comment: It seems like my original concerns with removing 7% from 100 should be 100/1.07 and not 100 - (100 * 0.07), but if you have 2 pecentages, 7 and 3, you can't do 100/1.07/1.03, you have to do 100/(1.07 + 0.03), how do you handle this in code.